# LFTP - Native library for Java

Tags: java, lftp

Is there a client for LFTP written in Java? I need to migrate an existing application using FTP fo LFTP but the restriction is use pure Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I google "lftp" I get the idea it is a client program only, not a protocol on its own. Are you sure you are not talking about SFTP?

Comment: Yes, LFTP, it's weird to me too. Actually we have systems running SFTP. But my new requirement talks about Lftp....?
That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I also don't know an lftp protocol. Could you point out the protocol's defintion like an RFC or something? Which server software are you using, maybe we can infer protocol information from that

Comment: Either point to documentation describing it, or you are simply misinterpreting the requirements.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. Better, I'll ask: What is LFTP? And what is the difference with other xFTPs?

Comment: Guys.. LFTP does exist, and its much faster than using ftp or sftp. here is the page for it: https://lftp.yar.ru/

I am still looking for the java API, will try to update if I do find it.

Answer (score 2):

LFTP is a program, not a protocol/server, therefore there is no "client" for it.

LFTP program can act as a client itself for the following protocols:

FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, HFTP, FISH, SFTP